# Is there such a thing as an optimum size for democracy?

Tags: democracy

Democracy has been around for a long time, and varying through history, it has worked out more-or-less satisfactorily for the people.

In the world, people are usually nice, but some governments turn bad, to the point where it becomes obvious that people and their governments are not the same (e.g. when people stopped deliberate killing and left legal killing to their government, until to the point when the government decides to send its people into an unwanted war, or to start a civil war cleansing operation inside)

What I wonder:

- is there some optimum size, where people and demographic government fit best ?
- what are the constraints? does it even work on a world-wide area now or with an ever-growing/evolving population in the future ?

Comment: Where have you looked for answers, and what did you find out (e.g. with regard to ancient Greek city states that practiced early forms of democracy).

Comment: You offer no examples illustrating any of your claims and no sources to back up your premises. Doing either or both of those things would improve this question immensely.

Comment: One premise you offer is fatally flawed. Fertility rates are dropping below replacement levels all over the world and in many regions population decline is imminent. As well it's predicted that within the next century global population will enter steep decline. So no, we don't have "ever increasing population" to deal with. Quite the opposite. We are headed for population crash.

Comment: While the other question was asked earlier, this one is defenetly better formulated.

Answer (score -4):

Many would argue that there has never been a participatory democracy. In ancient Greece they recognized that a functional democracy would lead to the majority laying claim to unequal wealth distribution. When the United States was founded they reached the same conclusion as to that fatal flaw of functional democracy. In ancient Greece they attempted to solve the problem by reducing wealth inequality to prevent class warfare. In the United States they decided the best solution would be to reduce the democracy to a non functional state.

To be clear, what i mean by democracy in a non functional state is that public policy is invariably in diametric opposition to the majority attitudes, values, opinions, beliefs, desires and welfare. These kinds of woes cannot exist in a functional democracy. I shouldn't have to mention this here but the reason public policy is in such opposition to public will is because the ability of the unpriveleged masses to affect that public policy is effectively nil. At best a grass roots movement will accomplish nothing but waste, at worst it will just incite the rulers to double down on draconian handicaps and humiliation to deprive those masses of what little spare time they had to devote to political activism in between frantic bouts of competitive struggle for survival.

As for "optimal size", the more dense a population becomes, the more homogenous it becomes. It actually becomes easier to operate a functional democracy with increasing population, not harder, especially in the digital age, approaching the diamond age. So the "optimal size" is, "the bigger the better". It's also worth noting that the ultimate ideal of democracy is anarchy, with nobody in charge, nobody granted authority to coerce anyone for any reason.

Comment: Based on the past centuries, it seems like the United States model worked well. What do you mean by a non-functional state?

Comment: Worked well to accomplish what? Absurdly high rates of child mortality, iatrogenic disease, murder, obesity, poverty, malnutrition, degeneracy, jingoism, racism, xenophobia, disenfranchisement, imprisonment and wars?

Comment: United States ranks highest in child mortality of the top 40 industrialized nations and has been there for many years.